# Cannot get ngx-material-timepicker to work in my Angular Project

Tags: angular, npm-install, timepicker

In my Angular 14 project **ngx-material-timepicker** is not working.

It's showing this error:

> declare (property) TimepickerDirective.timepicker:
> NgxMaterialTimepickerComponent Type 'MatDatepicker' is missing
> the following properties from type 'NgxMaterialTimepickerComponent':
> eventService, domService, timeUpdated, cancelBtnTmpl, and 32
> more.ngtsc(2740)

Kindly anyone please tell me what is the solution for this:

Details:

it's installed:

```
npm i ngx-material-timepicker
```

It's imported in my app.module.ts:

```
import {NgxMaterialTimepickerModule} from 'ngx-material-timepicker';

imports: [NgxMaterialTimepickerModule]
```

my HTML:

```
<input [ngxTimepicker]="picker">
<ngx-material-timepicker #picker></ngx-material-timepicker>
```